# C# Form accessing anonymous objects

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I'm throwing the objects that I created with the usercontrol to the flowlayoutPanel as much as the number of data in my database, I want to reach the texts of the selected object when I press and select it.

```
public void getProduct(string type)
    {

        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
        ServerControl cs = new ServerControl();
        var result = cs.TakeInfo(type);

        for (int i = 0; i < cs.count; i++)
        {
            var tutucu = new UserControl1();
            tutucu.nametag = result[i].Name;
            tutucu.pricetag = result[i].Price;
            tutucu.pathtag = result[i].Path;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(tutucu);
        }

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0TaW.png)

Comment: "when I press and select it" Looks like a COMPOSITE control UserControl, which isn't surprising. What part of that UserControl, though, is being pressed to "select" it? You need to expose a custom EVENT for your UserControl when the user clicks on the appropriate part of it. Then you can subscribe to that event when you create it in the Form with your code above.